# Add methods container to another class

Tags: python, api, rest, instantiation

Lets consider that I have some model classes:

```
class UserModel(Model):
    title = StringType()

class ItemModel(Model):
    ...
```

Model here is just a validator (Schematics). But I have a database (MongoDB) and I want to add some operations to Model.

```
class CRUDOperations(object):
   def get(self):
       return "Get Method"
```

I want to somehow "insert" CRUDOperations into Model, and want it to be accessed like: `UserModel.crud.get()`, i.e. without creating instances. I tried to do it but failed, is there a common practice for this?

```
from schematics.models import Model
from schematics.types import StringType


class CRUDOperations(object):
    def __init__(self, model_cls):
            # Upd. i need access to model_cls to get
            # some class attributes like collection name, database name etc.
        self.model_cls = model_cls


    @classmethod
    def get_crud(cls, model_cls):
        cls.model_cls = model_cls
        return cls

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, oid=None):
            # and if i'll use mongo here i'll need to access pymongo driver
            # like this: cls.model_cls._col_.find_one({"_id": oid})
        return 'test ok! {}'.format(cls.model_cls)


class CRUDModel(Model):
    __crud__ = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CRUDModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print "CRUDModel.__init__"
        self.__crud__ = CRUDOperations(self).get_crud()

    @classmethod
    def crud(cls):
        if cls.__crud__ is None:    
            cls.__crud__ = CRUDOperations.get_crud(cls)
        return cls.__crud__


class TestModel(CRUDModel):
    title = StringType()    


def main():
    print TestModel.crud
    print TestModel.crud.get()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Yes, i know that there is many mistakes, but i tried many ways, so it's just code to show what i have and what i need to do (call crud operations for model like TestModel.crud.create({...}))

Answer (score 0):

Your `CRUDOperations` are instantiated with `self` in the `__init__` method of the `CRUDModel`. so they cannot be accessed as class operations on `CRUDModel`.

You should do something like:

```
class CRUDModel(Model):
    __crud__ = CRUDOperations(CRUDModel)
```

Also, it is bad practice to name variables using a double underscore. Double underscores are meant for language reserved words. Use single underscores.

Comment: The child classes for CRUDModel have some attributes defined like _collection_, _mongo_connection_, _database_ etc. i need access to final model class from CRUDOperations.

Answer (score 0):

I would make the `CRUDOperations` a regular object *(without class methods)* which requires a `CRUDModel` instance to initialize.

Then you make a `@property` *crud* on the `CRUDModel` that initializes in an internal variable `_crud_` a `CRUDOperations` instance by passing `self` to it, and from then on just returns it.

With that you will have this seperation of functions to the `.crud` namespace, which is what you want I guess.

---

```
it's tricky since i want to have classmethods to have access w/o make instance.
```

If you don't want to create a new instance to have the `.crud.` then maybe you can rename all `CRUDOperations` methods to have a prefix `crud_` and make the instance functions that receive a `self` parameter.

Then use the `CRUDOperations` class as a mixin, by having the `CRUDModel` inherit from it. Then your functions will still be segmented with the `crud_` prefix and you won't have to create more than one instance.

Comment: i tried almost everything including @property, it's tricky since i want to have classmethods to have access w/o make instance.

Comment: @istinspring check my edit, maybe it will help. I'm unaware of any other practical way of doing this.